# Create 2D array of custom objects from XML

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, linq, 2d

I have the following XML, and I'm trying to get into an array using LINQ:

```
<doc>
  <rows>
    <cols>
      <a>value</a>
      <b>value</b>
      <c>value</c>
      <d>value</d>
    </cols>
    // multiple col elements
 </rows>
 // multiple rows elements, each has a set of col elements
</doc>
// single doc (root) element
```

using this code:

```
ObjectType[][] var = (
from e in XDocument.Load("Test.xml").Root.Elements()
select (
from cols in e.Elements("cols")
select new ObjectType
{
a = (int)e.Element("a"),
b = (int)e.Element("b"),
c = (int)e.Element("c"),
d = (int)e.Element("d")
}).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Where ObjectType is a simple structure of ints: a, b, c, and d.  The XML looks properly-formatted, but I keep getting System.ArgumentNullException.  From what I can make out in the debugger, it doesn't get past the first  element.

How is my brain failing me on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be like this

```
a = (int)cols.Element("a"),
b = (int)cols.Element("b"),
c = (int)cols.Element("c"),
d = (int)cols.Element("d")
```

use cols instead of e, e is for rows. 
also you have to change the word value in your xml to integer numbers